# How to format a number in thousands in SQL

Tags: sql, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a number like 238350.50 into "238" with SQL. I round to the nearest thousend using `ROUND(number_x, -3)` and it works fine but I can't get rid of the hundreds digits. A few more examples of how the formatting should work:

- 499.99 becomes 0
- 500 becomes 1
- 1250 becomes 1
- 22500 becomes 23
- 231600 becomes 232
- etc.

You can think of it like the "k" formatting f.e. 10.000 becomes "10k".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tag the DBMS(i.e. `MS SQL`,`Oracle`, etc.) that you are using.

Comment: To get a number that is a thousand times smaller, use the division operator: `number_x / 1000`. Getting rid of the decimal digits in a non-rounding fashion is different on different dialects of SQL, which you haven't tagged, but you can work around using `ROUND(number_x / 1000 - 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round it by the 1000, divide by the 1000

```
ROUND(number_x, -3)/1000
```

> ```
> with cte as (
> select 499.99 as number_x from dual
> union all select 500 from dual
> union all select 1250 from dual
> union all select 22500 from dual
> union all select 231600 from dual
> )
> select number_x, ROUND(number_x, -3)/1000 as new_number_x
> from CTE
> ```

| NUMBER_X | NEW_NUMBER_X |
| --- | --- |
| 499.99 | 0 |
| 500 | 1 |
| 1250 | 1 |
| 22500 | 23 |
| 231600 | 232 |

Or divide first, then round it.

```
ROUND(number_x/1000)
```

Comment: Apparently I was braindead for a second and forgot basic mathmatics... Thanks a lot!